# MySQL (mariaDB) Connection Error with SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, virtualbox, mariadb

Hello I have a mariaDB database on a Ubuntu server running in a virtual box.
With 'Sequal Pro' i can connect without any problems (with the ssh option).
Port forwarding like this: HOST 127.0.0.1 3306 GAST 10.0.2.15 3306

But in my python application i can't connect, or better it lost the connection before it can do something, with the following error:

> OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL
>   server during query') None None

I use SqlAlchemy with the mysqldb connector, like this:
In the **init**.py file in models directory:

```
# for this must install pymsql (pip install pymysql)
DATABASE = 'mysql+pymysql://<user>:<password>@127.0.0.1/fist-test'

app.debug = DEBUG
app.secret_key = 'secret-key123'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DATABASE
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

In the project main directory in the main.py file:

```
from models import db

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    db.create_all()
    return 'create objects...'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In models is also some model class:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

class User(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'users'

     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = Column(String)
     fullname = Column(String)
     password = Column(String)

     def __init__(self, name, fullname, password):
         self.name = name
         self.fullname = fullname
         self.password = password

     def __repr__(self):
        return "<User('%s','%s', '%s')>" % (self.name, self.fullname, self.password)
```

Hope someone can help me to understand and solve the problem.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because MariaDB has a much shorter default timeout of 600 seconds. See the timeout documentation here: [flask-sqlalchemy timeout docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/#timeouts)

I would recommend setting the SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE to less than 600 seconds so that the server does not time out.